# What's the best way to find the physical source of a wifi signal?

Tags: wifi

I'm trying to track down the owner of an offensively titled wifi network. The area is densely populated and there are many wifi networks operating.
Is this possible?

Comment: That's my access point.

Answer (score 6):

I'd strongly recommend ignoring it.

You could build an extended range directional antenna (google for "cantenna") and try to triangulate the source.  You can also use kismet to get a nice signal strength indication from your wifi adapter that might help you estimate distance.  These could help narrow it down.

But then what?  Are you going to confront a stranger, accusing him of being an evil person?  Are you going to expect the police to help?  Are you going to break the law and seek vengeance?  Maybe he put that name on the adapter just to bait easily offended people, and wants to meet them and beat them up.  Think twice about what you might do, and how badly it might go before proceeding.  Ignoring the name is a much more practical answer.

Comment: They actually make highly directional Wifi antennas for this purpose.  I've seen them at my business used to track down rogue wifi hotspots (something which is against company policy).  Of course, in that case, there is a recourse defined once the hotspot is identified because all employees have already agreed to abide by company policy, which avoids many of the issues you mention.

Comment: Thanks. It's not about confrontation. It's more about curiosity.

Comment: I don't think there are many people with the sense of humor to put up an offensive WiFi ESSID but who are stuck up enough to want to beat up anyone who is offended by it.

Comment: @forest , I envy you your naivety. :-) Too many people will put up racist, hateful stuff simply because they’re bigots who think they’re entitled to be bigots. They might be doing this to taunt someone into a fight, just for an excuse to beat someone up. That’s why I cautioned the original poster to ignore it for his own safety. Unfortunately, the world still has way too many people who think this is acceptable behavior.